# How to remove spaces from javascript file using php?

Tags: php, javascript, compression

I want to compress js files and convert into single line at the time of loading using php.when I removes the spaces with 'preg_replace' an error occurs,  ';' missing in line 234.
   The cause is some lines are not ending with ';'.For eg

```
          var flag='value'  // here not ended with ';'
          var test='value';
```

And when I minifies, it looks like

```
          var flag='value' var test='value';
```

So error occurs.

How can I minify js files with some lines not ending with ';'

Comment: make them all end with ; if needed and remember to remove all comments

Comment: @corroded I've never seen IE do that.

Comment: cry like a baby? good for you sir

Comment: @corroded: neither have I. All browsers will fail if the JS is minified with lacking semicolons. The one thing that makes IE cry and Fx not are trailing commas in object lists `{ "a":1, "b":2,}`

Comment: that too. i also get those trailing comma failures. but i do remember at one point that it cried just because of a missing semi-colon. or maybe of the console.log..which was incidentally missing a semi-colon. mmm. in any case, ie is a cry baby

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use a real parser based on the [rules for automatic semi colon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion/2846298#2846298).

Otherwise if you do (i.e. use a regex)...

```
$str = preg_replace('/(?<!;)\s*(\n|\z)/', ";$1", $str);
```

...you are going to munch valid JavaScript, e.g.

```
var a = 'a',
    b = 'bob';
```

...which will become...

```
var a = 'a',;
    b = 'bob';
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/WCplAC2r).

There are plenty of [existing JavaScript packers/minifiers](http://google.com/search?q=php%20javascript%20minifier).